# Passing additional cell data into JqGrid - while keeping sorting/grouping working

Tags: jqgrid

We are loading local data into jqgrid using the "jsonstring" datatype (I think this should behave the same as an AJAX request managed by jqgrid?).  We are also using groupBy, sorting and custom cell formatting. I'm trying to get this working with *structured* cell data, like so:

```
var jqGridData = {"total":1,"page":1,"records":10,
         "rows":[{
                        "id":"24_DisclosureFI",
                        "cell":["True", {"Value":"24_DisclosureFI","Source":"Input","OriginalValue":null}]
                ]} }
```

and so on. The idea being that some of our cellAttr function can use the additional info to make decisions on how to format that specific cell. However, adding this extended structure causes issues with grouping.

We've included a sortType function which gets the embedded cell value, and a customFormatter that does the same. These work, however when doing a groupBy it just takes the first cell value it finds and sticks everything in it. I've tried defining isInTheSameGroup() but it never gets called when we have the structured data (it works fine on non structured cell data).

If we turn off the structured data, all works fine (except we can't display the cell formatting we want). If we turn off the grouping, then the sorting/cell formatting works fine. But can't seem to find a combination where both works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You describes many different problems in your question bot you don't posted JavaScript code which demonstrate your attempts. The value of `jqGridData` seems me strange. In any way I suppose that most of your problems could be solved by small changing of input data for the grid and by usage of `datatype: "local"` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"`. For more detailed answer I need more information about what you do. It's better for other readers if you separate problem: one problem per one question.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I'll try to put a simple example together that demonstrates the problem without the rest of our plumbing code. The issue appears to come down to two places.

One, the use of "if (typeof v !== "object" &&" in groupingPrepare, and the use of $.jgrid.getAccessor in _getGroup.